# Ionic angular app stuck on white "loader". Web app works correct

Tags: c#, android, angular, ionic-framework

Console log: http://dpaste.com/2YCFB8S

My web ionic app works without problems. When I install an app on phone, I've got any loader and that's it… just stucks.

Ionic info: 
Ionic:

> ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.4.0 (C:\Users\ES property\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
>   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
>   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

> cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed
>   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.3
>   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.5, (and 4 other plugins)

System:

> Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\ES property\AppData\Local\Android\sdk)
>   NodeJS            : v8.12.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
>   npm               : 3.10.10
>   OS                : Windows 10

Comment: You can inspect the app using Chrome Dev Tools 'chrome://inspect', and check getting any runtime errors.

Comment: I dont have an errors in web, as i said. Only through app on phone

Answer (score 0):

If you have errors while deploying on your smartphone, just connect your phone on USB to your computer and Inspect the web View through your deployed app.

In order to do that, just go to the URL "chrome://inspect/#devices" on your google chrome browser while your phone has opened the app.

Then you can click on your device and inspect the console to see if you've got any errors (will work for most cases).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about the splashscreen? If so,

Have you added the hide method inside app.component?

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.splashScreen.hide();      
    });
  }
```

I remember having a similar problem and I tried lots of things to make it work. I have these lines about splashscreen in my config.xml. Maybe they can help you as well.

```
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

Lastly, have you changed default splashscreen images in config.xml? Name changes might cause a problem as well.